# How to parse data under Textview

Tags: android, xml, parsing, textview

can anybody help me? I'm writing an application for Android that parses data from internet and writes them into TextView.

```
TextView[] dva = new TextView[sitesList.getDva().size()];

// Set the result text in textview and add it to layout 
for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getDva().size(); i++) {       
    dva[i].new TextView(this);
    dva[i].setText("KOSILO: "+sitesList.getDva().get(i));

layout.addView(dva[i]);
```

Under dva[i] I parse 5 objects that I would like them to display them under one TextView.

```
TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kosilodva);
    textView1.setText("KOSILO: "+sitesList.getDva().get(i));
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance to everybody who is willing to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setText why don't you try append,

Replace this,

```
 textView1.setText("KOSILO: "+sitesList.getDva().get(i));
```

with,

```
textView1.append("KOSILO: "+sitesList.getDva().get(i));
```

Comment: It didn't work. I have to somehow display dva[i] under TextView.

Comment: are you using this line inside your foe loop,
TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kosilodva); if so place it outside the for loop, and try append method